# How to make the align environment break at the right place?

Tags: line-breaking, align, page-breaking

I need to break an `align` environment. Is it possible to give hints to LaTeX about where to break or, better, where not to break?

Here is a example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=5cm, 
            paperheight=3cm,
            margin=1mm,
            bottom=.5\baselineskip]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}           
\allowdisplaybreaks         

\begin{document}

We have

\begin{align*}
  A + B + C &= a + b + c + d \\ 
  & \qquad \qquad + e + f \\
  &= a' + b' + c' + d' \\ 
  & \qquad \qquad + e' + f' \\
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simple: don't use `\allowdisplaybreaks` and, instead, place `\displaybreak` on the line after which you want the break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can prevent breaking by using `\\*` instead of `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=5cm,
            paperheight=3cm,
            margin=1mm,
            bottom=.5\baselineskip]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

We have    
\begin{align*}
  A + B + C &= a + b + c + d \\
  & \qquad \qquad + e + f \\
  &= a' + b' + c' + d' \\*  %<<-- don't break after this line
  & \qquad \qquad + e' + f'
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The macro `\allowdisplaybreaks` is to be used in two cases:

1. the document is being prepared and we don't need to be fussy about page breaks
2. the document is subject to automatic typesetting, so nobody can examine the page breaks

The second case is irrelevant, because there is no control on the page breaks to begin with. The first case is what we're concerned with.

During the final revision of the document, when the text is essentially in its definitive form, remove `\allowdisplaybreaks` and use `\displaybreak` where you *do* want a page break

```
We have
\begin{align*}
  A + B + C &= a + b + c + d \\
  & \qquad \qquad + e + f \displaybreak \\
  &= a' + b' + c' + d' \\
  & \qquad \qquad + e' + f'
\end{align*}
and something else.
```

Note that a blank line must *never* precede any display environment. And *never* is used with its main meaning: not *usually* or *mostly*, but never.